# Should the Volume of a Solid of Revolution always be the same when rotated around the x-axis than around y-axis?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

So for example, take:

$y = 2x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ around the $x$-axis.

The volume should be $4π/3 u^3$.

Now rotating $y = 2x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ around the $y$-axis:

1) Rewrite the function: $x = y/2$.

2) Recalculate limits: $[0,2]$.

I get: $4π/3 u^3$ -again!

Is this true with all functions and axes?

I ask because, I'm studying for a test and can't seem to find examples of the same function being rotated around different axes. Often times I get different results.

I appreciate your time, I believe many others are wondering the same.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the function $y=1$ on the interval $[100,101]$?

Comment: @EthanBolker, I believe that produces a different result! I'm not sure cause there's no $x$. I'm sorry but sometimes when I get confused with a complex concept I seem to forget basic stuff.

Comment: Draw a picture. The area you're rotating is just a square. Around the $x$ axis it makes a cylinder. Around the $y$ axis it makes a washer-like thing. You don't need calculus to find the volumes.

Comment: Thanks for putting it that way, Ethan. Although, there are cylinders and cones with the same volume, a function may not describe two different shapes with the same volume. Correct? Or will the washer and the cylinder have the same volume? Not trying to give ya a hard time. Just want to know the answer to the question.